# What does "do't" mean?

Tags: meaning, contractions, archaic-language, elision, early-modern-english

I found this line in *Hamlet* by William Shakespeare.

> I'll do't. Dost thou come here to whine?

What does "do't" mean? Google returneth only "don't". Is "do't" an alternative spelling of "don't"? Is "I'll don't" a common phrase in English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this link](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/hamlet/page_296.html). "I'll do't" means "I will **do it**". It's not an alternative spelling of *don't*. Early English uses a lot more contractions in writing, and plays, especially Shakespeare's plays, use a lot because they're written in verse and need to shorten words and phrases to maintain the meter.

Comment: Yes, though I think it's less a matter of meter than the fact of representing spoken language. Also, Early Modern English tended to contract pronouns, or omit them altogether (*th'art*, *is't*, *y'are*, and the contraction of *he* to *'a* and *his* to *'s*), where today we prefer to contract or omit auxiliary verbs. That very different colloquial rhythm is difficult for actors coming to Shakespeare for the first time.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, again, y'are prob'ly right about't, & y'are certain to be better informed about't than I am.

Comment: I'm occasionally tempted to throw *'a*, *'s*,*'n* into the ring as the long-sought genderless 3d person singular pronoun.